# Azure - Throttle API based on Number of calls not by who called it

Tags: azure, api, gateway, throttling

I have an API endpoint that I want to throttle using my API gateway in Azure, but it seems like throttling is always based on someone's IP address, in turn restricting a single user from only being able to call so many times per X seconds/minutes. I want to throttle solely by the number of request per second. I don't care who calls it, it just can't exceed 100 requests per second.

So if 101 different people (with different IP addresses) all call the API at the same time, it will work for the first 100 people, but the 101th person will receive an error message saying something like "Too many requests, try again later"

Is this something that is even possible? How would I go about handling that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using API Management? If so, you can rate limit at the subscription level. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies?msclkid=b2edcf28c68711eca92149b8c5344a97#LimitCallRate

Comment: @nullforce I am not, but I think I can set one up. Thanks!